# Mount share on domain-joined-server from non-domain-joined client

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-share

I tried to mount a share on a domain-joined-server with a non-domain-joined client.

**Now my problem is**: when prompted for credentials only username in form "domain\username" works, if I try "username" the server rejects the credentials.

Is there a way to circumvent this behavior by setting something like a default search or lookup domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the server has to authenticate the user somehow, either from AD or from the local SAM database. Since these are non-domain joined clients the server can't find a valid user in AD or the local SAM for the incoming username, hence why you need to prepend the domain name to the username when connecting. If you don't want the users to have to do that then you need to do one of two things:

1. Join the clients to the domain and create a domain user account for each user. Add the domain user accounts to the Share and NTFS permissions on the share(s).
2. Create matching local user accounts on the file server for each workstation user account and set the password to the same as the workstation user account.

If you don't want to do either one then you're going to have to continue prepending the domain name to the username when accessing the share(s).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to specify username in either NT4-form ("DOMAIN\UserName") or UPN form ("username@domain.fqdn").

Comment: no possibility to go without the domain? we only have 1 domain in our forest so i dont want to burden our employees with the need to put the domain name in front oder after their username.